# Showing $x_1x_3 + 2x_2 + x_1 = 4$ is not a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

> Prove that $x_1x_3 + 2x_2 + x_1 = 4$ is not a linear equation.

I do understand that in order to be a linear equation, it must fall inside the graph linearly. This equation does show a linear equation but I don't get it why it is not a linear equation.

I am sorry, I am really new to linear algebra.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Look back in your book or class notes to find an actual definition of "linear equation". That phrase does not mean "fall inside the graph linearly".

Comment: Hey! Thanks, have looked though but they love to give examples but not a definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint $\#1$:**

Typically, an equation which is "linear" will meet the condition that two members of your set of variables are not multiplied together.

For example, consider $f(x) = x^2.$ This is not linear, because we have a term that is $x\cdot x$. (Of course this also means that if you have a variable raised to a power which is not $0$ or $1$, you can immediately conclude the equation is nonlinear.)

Similarly, $f(x,y) = xy$ is not linear, because here we have two variables, $x,y$, being multiplied together.

In your case, since you're in a linear algebra course, your variables often will be $x_i$ for some integer $i$. With this in mind, what can you conclude about your equation?

---

**Hint $\#2$:**

> Look at the first term of your equation. If *any* term in the equation is nonlinear, the equation is nonlinear. *(Assuming of course the term is not somehow negated - for example, $x^2 - x^2$ is still linear since it's $0$, but that's a fringe concern and not relevant here.)*

Comment: Rule of a thumb:

In order to be a non-linear equation,
1) f(x,y) = xy
2) f(x) = x^n
3) Trigo

Am I correct?

Comment: It's an alright rule of thumb. Generally, if you want the "most general" form of a linear equation, with variables $x_1, ..., x_n$ and constants $c_1, ..., c_n$, then 

$$f(x_1,...,x_n) = c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + ... + c_n x_n$$

Basically anything not in the above form or convertable to that form is nonlinear. So if they're raised to other powers, you have $x_i x_j$ or something like that, or something like $\sin(x_i)$, then they're all definitely nonlinear. This also would include stuff like $\log(x_i), e^{x_i},$ and so on.

Comment: I see, a million thanks for helping me out!

How about if they introduced a constant:
I came across a question,
if m is constant, prove that is a linear equation:
mx1 - m^2x2 = 9
It states that it is only a linear equation of m is either 0 or 1.

But my argument is that:
Regardless of what number m is, it is still a linear equation as it is not an unknown but a constant.